# Phaser Game Keyboard Arrow Keys to Mobile Touch

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser and am following this tutorial here: https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part7

What do I need to change for use on a mobile cell phone browser to make the player automatically run to the right and jump when the screen is tapped?  I've searched for ages but can't find the answer and am trying to learn

```
//  Input Events
cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();


if (cursors.left.isDown)
{
    player.setVelocityX(-160);

    player.anims.play('left', true);
}
else if (cursors.right.isDown)
{
    player.setVelocityX(160);

    player.anims.play('right', true);
}
else
{
    player.setVelocityX(0);

    player.anims.play('turn');
}

if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
{
    player.setVelocityY(-330);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

Add an input handler to your general game that calls a 'jump' function when a pointer is down.

```
this.input.on('pointerdown', this.jump, this);
```

Jump should now verify that the player can jump. Something like:

```
jump() {
  if (this.player.body.touching.down) {
    this.player.setVelocityY(-330);
  }
}
```

To have your player automatically move at a speed, you can just set the player's body velocity when you're creating the player.

```
this.player.body.velocity.x = 160;
```

Note that if you want to keep the current ability to control the `player`, another option is to have actual buttons on the screen that the user can tap/click on to have the `player` move/act accordingly. There's an [official plugin for Phaser 2](https://phaser.io/shop/plugins/virtualjoystick) that does this, that you could look at.

Comment: Free example is here https://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/virtual-gamecontroller